# Error con dos unidades de persistencia: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.annotation.processing.FilerException:

Tags: java, netbeans, jpa, java-8

Al compilar y ejecutar en el IDE funciona bien la aplicación pero al generar el jar me genera este error:

```
An annotation processor threw an uncaught exception.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.annotation.processing.FilerException: Attempt to recreate a file for type howdenwacolda.entidades.Roles_
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor.process(CanonicalModelProcessor.java:407)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:705)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:856)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:381)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:370)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:361)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:56)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.main(Main.java:42)
Caused by: javax.annotation.processing.FilerException: Attempt to recreate a file for type howdenwacolda.entidades.Roles_
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacFiler.checkNameAndExistence(JavacFiler.java:522)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacFiler.createSourceOrClassFile(JavacFiler.java:396)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacFiler.createSourceFile(JavacFiler.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor.generateCanonicalModelClass(CanonicalModelProcessor.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor.generateCanonicalModelClasses(CanonicalModelProcessor.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor.process(CanonicalModelProcessor.java:403)
    ... 13 more
C:\Users\Priojects\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HowdenWacolda\nbproject\build-impl.xml:955: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Priojects\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HowdenWacolda\nbproject\build-impl.xml:295: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

y este es mi archivo persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="HowdenWacoldaPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.AutorizadoRamos</class>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.Ramos</class>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.TipoIntermediario</class>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.Empleados</class>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.IndicadorVinculacion</class>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.EstadoAutorizacion</class>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.AutorizadoRamos</class>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.TipoIdentificacion</class>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.Roles</class>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.Usuarios</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=SucisHowdenWacolda"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="P@ssw0rd"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
  <persistence-unit name="HowdenWacoldaPU2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.AutorizadoRamos</class>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.Empleados</class>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.EstadoAutorizacion</class>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.IndicadorVinculacion</class>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.Ramos</class>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.Roles</class>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.TipoIdentificacion</class>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.TipoIntermediario</class>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.Usuarios</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=SucisHowdenWacolda"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="P@ssw0rd"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Agradezco su ayuda, llevo ya rato en esto.

Comment: Hola Sebastian. Por favor, no dupliques preguntas, si tienes que modificar algo, puedes pulsar en el botón [edit]. He eliminado la otra pregunta al ser un duplicado casi exacto de esta. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y [answer] en el centro de ayuda, donde encontrarás consejos para estos casos.

Answer (score 2):

Ya encontré la solución, era agregar una propiedad nueva a cada unidad de persistencia "HowdenWacoldaPU", para la primera agregue

```
<property name="eclipselink.canonicalmodel.subpackage" value="dev"/>
```

y para la segunda unidad de persistencia "HowdenWacoldaPU2"

```
 <property name="eclipselink.canonicalmodel.subpackage" value="prod"/>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="HowdenWacoldaPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.AutorizadoRamos</class>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.Ramos</class>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.Roles</class>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.Empleados</class>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.TipoIdentificacion</class>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.IndicadorVinculacion</class>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.EstadoAutorizacion</class>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.TipoIntermediario</class>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.Usuarios</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.canonicalmodel.subpackage" value="dev"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=SucisHowdenWacolda"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="P@ssw0rd"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
  <persistence-unit name="HowdenWacoldaPU2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.Ramos</class>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.Roles</class>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.Empleados</class>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.TipoIdentificacion</class>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.IndicadorVinculacion</class>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.AutorizadoRamos</class>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.EstadoAutorizacion</class>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.TipoIntermediario</class>
    <class>howdenwacolda.entidades.Usuarios</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.canonicalmodel.subpackage" value="prod"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=SucisHowdenWacoldaDos"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="P@ssw0rd"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

ademas en el import que me generaba la falla (`import howdenwacolda.entidades.Usuarios_;`)
lo cambie por `import howdenwacolda.entidades.dev.Usuarios_;`

Answer (score 0):

ingresar las clases de entidad para cada unidad de persistencia manualmente no debe incluir la misma clase en más de una unidad de persistencia, esto deberia solucionar tu problema ya que el error se debe a eso.

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta alesilvabk,
Lo que pasa es que es una aplicacion de escritorio y no tengo un web.xml.

Comment: @SebastianAlbornoz El problema es que tienes varias clases en la misma unidad de persistencia en el archivo persistence